# How to convert 4 uint8_t to a single float using bitwise operations

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, microcontroller

I've 4 variables uint8_t that are a single float that was divided into parts using bitwise operations. I can't find how to pack them again together to a single float variable. Can someone advice me?

Comment: Not unless you explain the manner in which the original float was split (i.e. post the relevant piece of code).

Comment: No language specified - I've assumed C and added a tag - please change this if it's no correct.

Comment: There is also that nasty little bit of *endianness* to consider. If you split the float into the 4 parts, then you put it back together in the same way you took it apart. Otherwise you need to know which is the MSB and LSB and the endianness of your hardware.

Comment: "I've 4 variables uint8_t that are a single float that was divided into parts using bitwise operations." --> Until that code is posted, it is unclear what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a union, e.g.

```
union {
    uint8_t a[4];
    float f;
} U;
```

or just use `memcpy`:

```
uint8_t a[4];
float f;

memcpy(&f, a, sizeof(a));
```

Note that it's your responsibility to load the required 8 bit values into `a` in the appropriate order.